# I've worked for hours & still failed, getting phpMyAdmin to work in my WAMP setup

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I'm trying to develop my website rebuild locally on my XP SP3 machine. I have the following installed: WordPress version 3.5.1; Apache version 2.4.4; PHP version 5.4.16; MySQL version 5.6.12. The PC has Apache & wampache running fine, as is WAMP. I cannot, however, use phpMyAdmin. I keep getting the 404 Not Found error message, even though Localhost returns 'It works!'. My attempt at adding [local host] to the index.php in my c:\wordpress\www folder, as per nugget49's successful efforts. I used and didn't use the brackets, failed both ways. I added the versions of the programs I listed above (where index.php already had indications for them) and then removed them; again, neither worked. Please help if you can, thanks!

Comment: Oops!  I meant c:\wamp\www folder - my brain is mush now.

Answer (score 0):

It sound like you have 2 Apache servers running at the same time. You say you have `Apache` and `wampapache` services running?

You also say when you run `localhost` you get the `It works!` message from apache. That message is from a standalone Apache install and **NOT** from a WAMPServer install of Apache. With WAMPServer you shold see a WAMPServer homepage.

So I guess you tried installing Apache and maybe MySQL and PHP manually before discovering WAMPServer. If so check your system and **uninstall the other** Apache i.e. the Apache you installed before trying WAMPServer.
Also if you tried installing PHP and MySQL manually i.e. not via WAMPServer, uninstall those also.

Answer (score 0):

When I click on start Wampserver,  I get a listed-on its side 'WAMPSERVER 2.4' box with "Powered by Alter Way" left-right listing at the top.  Is that the WAMPServer homepage?  Or should it be a kind of localhost page?

This is so frustrating, I don't have much time left for this & the dopey book I bought dodges the hole install issue.  I might just build dreaded template pages for my website, I can't stand this anymore.  I  believe I installed Apache by myself, this is madness but thanks for jumping in & for your comments.

In my 'program files' folder, I have an 'Apache Software Foundation' folder, nothing else related to Apache.  In 'Services (Local)' Control Panel listings, the only one there is for Apache2.2.  I had a free HTML4 media player that was working great for me for years, easy to maintain, but of course it won't work for me now.  I don't have the money to rebuild other than this "so easy to setup & use" option that I can't succeed with.  So it goes, thanks again.